# Function in jQuery no longer works when called

Tags: jquery, function, calling-convention

I wrote a jQuery function that calculates the total for dynamic divs. When I execute the function directly in the event handler, it works fine:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.priceText:not(:last)', function() {
var total = 0;
$(this).each(function() {
        if ((this.value) != '') {
            total += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    }
)
if (isNaN(total) == false) {
    $('#total-price').html(total);
}
else {
    total = 0;
}
});
```

However, if I try to run the same function by *calling* it, it no longer works properly:

```
function calcTotal(pricesToAdd, divToUpdate) {
var total = 0;
$(pricesToAdd).each(function() {
        if ((pricesToAdd.value) != '') {
            total += parseFloat(pricesToAdd.value);
        }
    }
)
if (isNaN(total) == false) {
    $(divToUpdate).html(total);
}
else {
    total = 0;
}
}

$(document).on('keyup', '.priceText:not(:last)', function() {
calcTotal(this, '#total-price');
});
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: will u post HTML also? or create seperate fiddles (http://jsfiddle.net/) and add it in your question.

Comment: what do you mean by  'no longer works properly'. Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: It's tricky to post the HTML and/or use jsFiddle because the page uses quite a lot of code to generate dynamic content, and I'm also using Blade's templating engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 issues

1. this line: `calcTotal(this, '#total-price');` . `this` in this context is the **element that triggered the keyup event** not the collection matched by `'.priceText:not(:last)'`. Change your code to pass the whole collection like this: `calcTotal($('.priceText:not(:last)'), $('#total-price'));`
2. this bit `$(pricesToAdd).each(function() {  if ((pricesToAdd.value) != '')` you're attempting to loop over a collection but inside the loop you're referring to the collection again and not the object at the current index.

Also, I would pass the objects themselves to the function instead of just the selectors, just my preference though.

### Here is an example:

```js
function calcTotal(pricesToAdd, divToUpdate) {
    var total = 0;
    pricesToAdd.each(function (e,thisPrice) { // reference the element you iterate
        if ((thisPrice.value) != '') { // work with the current price
            total += parseFloat(thisPrice.value);
        }
    })
    if (isNaN(total) == false) {
       divToUpdate.html(total);
    } else {
        total = 0; 
    }
}

$(document).on('keyup', '.priceText:not(:last)', function () {
    // calcTotal(this, '#total-price'); // this was only sending the clicked element not the collection
     calcTotal($('.priceText:not(:last)'), $('#total-price')); // Pass the whole matched collection instead
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="priceText">
<br>
<input type="text" class="priceText">
<br>
<input type="text" class="priceText">
<br>
<input type="text" class="priceText">
<span id="total-price"></span>
```

Comment: Yup, we have a winner. Thanks @DelightedD0D! 

This actually helps me better understand how selecting elements works in this context.

Comment: @MaorPolak actually everyone got confused with the statement of yours. "when I execute the function directly in the event handler, it works fine"

Comment: @MaorPolak for what it's worth, Anoop is right. Your original method using with the code in the event handler directly could not have worked as intended for the same reason listed above. See http://jsfiddle.net/vbfue61f/39/

Comment: You guys are right, I see that it doesn't work on jsFiddle. It's possible that I originally had "$('.priceText:not(:last)')" instead of "$(this)" as the first selector. It was working properly, and the problems only started when I wanted to *call* the function instead of using the anonymous one. I have made quite a few changes to the code before posting.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.priceText:not(:last)', function() {
    calcTotal(this, '#total-price');
});
```

`this` should be `$(this)`
Try calling the function calcTotal() instead of adding an anonymous to call another function:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.priceText:not(:last)', calcTotal($(this), '#total-price'));
```

Supposing that function is correctly working, this should work.

Edit: if that doesn't works:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.priceText:not(:last)', function() {
    calcTotal($(this), '#total-price');
});
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying about re-selecting the DOM element by using $(this). I updated my code to reflect this.  

Your first suggestion, of omitting the anonymous function, generates an error.  

I've applied your second suggestion, but the function is still not working as it should.

Comment: You are making the exact same mistake as the OP, `this` in this context is the element that triggered the keyup event not the collection matched by '.priceText:not(:last)'. Using this code, only the current element is sent to the function. This is why no addition occurs.

Comment: True, as said it was working fine on the first way, I assumed it was working aswel, so I went to the jquery call